# search manipulation in SP2013

Tags: search, search-results

I am using SP2013 , on my site whenever a user searches for anything everything related to that comes up on screen it's a very nice feature but the problem is all the aspx files & related stuff which shall not be come up in the search , is there any way we can prevent that ???

Comment: Search is about finding "related stuff". Can you describe what "shall not come up"? What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: I am trying to prevent all the admin side's content not all but some .aspx pages & certain files which visitor should not come across in while searching.

Comment: Are you saying that system pages are showing up in your search results? What account are you using for crawling content?

Answer (score 0):

-Create Result Source and make Query

> Path:"mysiteurl/*"

-Go to your Search webpart use Created Result Source
-**ok** Now Check you will get all the result from your mysite only

Comment: I believe the question might have been more of a "how to filter out all aspx files" rather "search only in my site"

Comment: I tried but it shows no result when I search anything !

Comment: Justas that is also correct ! Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

it is little tricky to remove all the .aspx pages from the search. Becuase may be you remove all relevant pages as well. But if you know to certain pages. allitems.aspx,editform.aspx,mod-view.aspx etc from search. here are the steps:

- Go to SharePoint Central Administration site.
- Go to Manage service applications from Application Management page.
- On the Manage service applications page find a Search Service
  Application and click the name of that service application. Do not
  click the name for Search Service Application Proxy name.
- On the Search Administration page, from the left hand menu click
  Crawl Rules.
- On Manage Crawl Rules, click New Crawl Rule to create new crawl rule.
- On Add Crawl Rule page, in the Path field provide the below value.
  [Create each new rule for each of the below items.]

  http://*allitems.aspx
  http://*editform.aspx
  http://*dispform.aspx
  http://*my-sub.aspx
  http://*mod-view.aspx
- You can also provide any other value which you wish to exclude from
  the search results.
- Now, in the Crawl Configuration section, Exclude all items in this
  page radio button is selected. You should keep that as it is, if you
  want to exclude them items which match the above provided path.
- Or you should select Include all items in this path, if you want to
  include the above one in search results. Click Ok.
- Now, your crawl rule is created.
- Now, go to Content Sources page and start full crawl.

http://prajapati-jatin.blogspot.com/2011/10/exclude-allitemsaspx-pages-from.html

Also check this one: http://stevemannspath.blogspot.com/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-search-removing-junk.html